# Create different named lists in loop

Tags: c#, list

I have a List A filled with double variables from equations. Now I want to create an n amount of lists equal to the equations i have with different names each.

For Example take the first 6 elements from A, put them to List1, then the next 6 of A, put them to List2 and so on.

Already wrote a method which returns back the amount of equations as int. I know how to create lists, but doing that manually makes my code too big confusing. I want to know how to create Lists in a loop. (1st List is List1, 2nd List is List2...)

Comment: Please provide some codes you've done so far.

Comment: could you add the lists to a dictionary where the key is 1,2,3 ....

Comment: why don't you create an array of lists? or a list of lists? List<double>[] equationsCostants? So you can access to the elements by index equationsCostants[i]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    enum Equation
    {
        A,
        B,
        C
    }

    class Result
    {
        public readonly Equation Equation;
        public readonly double Value;

        public Result(Equation equation, double value)
        {
            Equation = equation;
            Value = value;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var results = GetGroupedResults();
        }

        static ILookup<Equation, Result> GetGroupedResults()
        {
            return GetResults().ToLookup(x => x.Equation);
        }

        static List<Result> GetResults()
        {
            return new List<Result>();
        }
    }
}
```